# C# Dropdownlist OnSelectedIndexChanged not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, selectedindexchanged

I have an issue with both `Dropdownlist_OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `Checkbox_OnCheckedChanged` events not firing from within an `UpdatePanel` after the `UpdatePanel` has been updated from the code behind.

As you can see from the code below the `DropDownList` and `CheckBoxes` bind on the client side and when loaded / reloaded all of the `Controls` bind to the values from the database.

When the page initially loaded with some data, both the `Dropdownlist_OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `Checkbox_OnCheckedChanged` events fire as expected. They also update the database values via the code behind.

However if, for example, I change the data range for my `GridView` data and therefore refresh the `UpdatePanel` and rebind all of the data, the `Dropdownlist_OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `Checkbox_OnCheckedChanged` events stop firing.

I have tried to diagnose this by adding various break points to the code behind when the `Dropdownlist_OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `Checkbox_OnCheckedChanged` events should be calling the relevant functions, however the breakpoints are never reached.

I also have `OnSelectedIndexChanged` enabled in the `GridView` where the above `Controls` are located and it fire as expected, every time... Even when the above `Controls` do not.

My code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="Downtime" Language="C#" 

MasterPageFile="~/Reporting/Reporting.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GensetDowntime.aspx.cs" Inherits="ReportingSystemV2.Reporting.GensetDowntime" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Reporting/Reporting.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ReportingSubContent" runat="server">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelDowntime" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <%--Summary Table--%>
                <div id="DowntimeSummaryDiv" visible="false" runat="server">
                    <table id="DowntimeSummary" class="table table-striped table-condensed" align="center" style="width: 50%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Gross Hours</th>
                                <th>Run Hours</th>
                                <th>Total Exempts</th>
                                <th>Total Non-Exempts</th>
                                <th>Difference</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSumGrossHrs" runat="server" ToolTip="Total hours in this period"></asp:Label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSumRunHours" runat="server" ToolTip="Engine running hours in this period"></asp:Label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSumTotExempts" runat="server" ToolTip="(hhhh:mm)"></asp:Label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSumTotNonExempts" runat="server" ToolTip="(hhhh:mm)"></asp:Label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSumDifference" runat="server" ToolTip="Difference (Minutes) = Gross Hours - (Run Hours + Total Exempt + Total Non-Exempt)"></asp:Label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <%--End of Summary Table--%>
            <%--Downtime Table--%>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="downtimeDiv" runat="server">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gridDowntime" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-striped table-condensed"
                        OnRowDataBound="gridDowntime_RowDataBound"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridDowntime_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        DataKeyNames="ID,ID_Location,iddown,idup,dtdown,dtup,isexempt" EmptyDataText="No exempts in the selected period.">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="dtdown" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}"
                                HeaderText="Down" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="dtup" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}"
                                HeaderText="Up" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="timedifference"
                                HeaderText="Duration (min)" DataFormatString="{0:D4}" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="REASON"
                                HeaderText="Reason" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exempt?">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDowntimeExempt" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDowntimeExempt_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Unverified</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDowntimeExempt" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"isexempt")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exclude?">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDowntimeExclude" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ISEXCLUDED")) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkDowntimeExclude_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Details" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--End of Downtime Table--%>

            <%--Shutdown Values--%>
            <div id="downtimeValueDiv" runat="server">
                <asp:GridView ID="gridDowntimeRecalc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                    CssClass="table table-striped table-condensed" Width="50%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="dtdown" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}"
                            HeaderText="Downtime" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="dtup" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}"
                            HeaderText="Uptime" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeDifference"
                            HeaderText="Duration (min)" DataFormatString="{0:D4}" />
                        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReset" runat="server" OnClick="lnkReset_Click" ToolTip="Reset">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-rotate-left"></span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <div class="span7 text-center">
                    <br />
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <div class="form-inline">
                            Events (min +/-):
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdjust" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAdjust_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">10</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>90</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>120</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>240</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--End of Shutdown Values--%>

            <%--Details Row--%>
            <div id="detailDiv" runat="server">
                <asp:GridView ID="gridDowntimeDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-condensed"
                    OnRowDataBound="gridDowntimeDetail_RowDataBound"
                    OnRowCommand="gridDowntimeDetail_RowCommand"
                    DataKeyNames="ExemptId">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBack" runat="server" Text="Back" CommandName="Back" 
                                    CommandArgument="<% Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>"
                                    CausesValidation="false">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Timestamp" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}" HeaderText="Time Stamp" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reason" HeaderText="Reason" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Event" HeaderText="Event" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <%--End of Details Row--%>

            <%--Notes Row--%>
            <div class="span7 text-center">
                <div id="notesDiv" runat="server">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Notes</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbNotes" runat="server" MaxLength="40" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSave" runat="server" OnClick="lnkSave_Click">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span> Save
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBack1" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBack_Click">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></span> Back
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%--End of Notes Row--%>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

My code behind is:

```
namespace ReportingSystemV2.Reporting
{
    public partial class GensetDowntime : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ReportingSystemDataContext RsDc = new ReportingSystemDataContext();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Attach to UserControl Event
        Master.reportDateChanged += new EventHandler(report_DateChanged);
    }

    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportingBase f = (ReportingBase)Page.Master;

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (f.IdLocation != 0)
            {
                if (f.endDate < f.startDate)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "bootstrap_alert.warning('alert-warning', 'Oops!', 'Please select a valid date range..');", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    BindDowntime();
                    bindDowntimeSummary();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "bootstrap_alert.warning('alert-warning', 'Oops!', 'Please select a site..');", true);
            }

            showDowntimeDetail(false);
        }
    }

    private void report_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If the user changes the date lets update the table
        BindDowntime();
        bindDowntimeSummary();

        showDowntimeDetail(false);
    }

    #region Overview

    protected void BindDowntime()
    {
        // Binds the downtime to the gv
        // Hide the downtime ID
        ReportingBase f = (ReportingBase)Page.Master;
        gridDowntime.Columns[1].Visible = false;

        gridDowntime.DataSource = RsDc.FILTEREXEMPTS(f.IdLocation, f.startDate, f.endDate.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59));
        gridDowntime.DataBind();

        if (gridDowntime.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // CSS Header Sytle
            gridDowntime.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            gridDowntime.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }          
    }

    protected void bindDowntimeSummary()
    {
        ReportingBase f = (ReportingBase)Page.Master;

        // Binds the summary at the top of the page for the user to see the downtime at a glance
        int hrsRun = 0;
        TimeSpan tsGrossHours = (f.endDate - f.startDate);

        if (f.startDate.Date == f.endDate.Date)
        {
            tsGrossHours = tsGrossHours.Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
            hrsRun = Convert.ToInt32(RsDc.ACTUALHOURSRUN(f.IdLocation, f.startDate, f.endDate).FirstOrDefault().ACTUALHOURSRUN);
        }
        else
        {
            hrsRun = Convert.ToInt32(RsDc.ACTUALHOURSRUN(f.IdLocation, f.startDate, f.endDate).FirstOrDefault().ACTUALHOURSRUN);
        }

        lblSumGrossHrs.Text = tsGrossHours.TotalHours.ToString();
        lblSumRunHours.Text = hrsRun.ToString();

        int totalExempts = 0;
        int totalNonExempts = 0;

        // Loop Grid
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridDowntime.Rows)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl = row.Cells[5].FindControl("ddlDowntimeExempt") as DropDownList;

            CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox();
            cbx = row.Cells[6].FindControl("chkDowntimeExclude") as CheckBox;

            if (!cbx.Checked)
            {
                if (ddl.SelectedValue == "1")
                {
                    totalExempts += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    totalNonExempts += Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].Text);
                }
            }
        }

        TimeSpan tsTotalExempts = new TimeSpan(0, totalExempts, 0);
        TimeSpan tsTotalNonExempts = new TimeSpan(0, totalNonExempts, 0);

        lblSumTotExempts.Text = ((tsTotalExempts.Days * 24 + tsTotalExempts.Hours).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ":" + tsTotalExempts.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
        lblSumTotNonExempts.Text = ((tsTotalNonExempts.Days * 24 + tsTotalNonExempts.Hours).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + ":" + tsTotalNonExempts.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));

        TimeSpan tsHrsRun = new TimeSpan((int)hrsRun, 0, 0);
        lblSumDifference.Text = (tsGrossHours.TotalMinutes - (tsHrsRun.TotalMinutes + tsTotalExempts.TotalMinutes + tsTotalNonExempts.TotalMinutes)).ToString();

        DowntimeSummaryDiv.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void gridDowntime_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // Once data is loaded into the gv apply the ddl's for the shutdowns
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlDowntimeExempt");
            //ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlDowntimeExempt_SelectedIndexChanged);
            //ddl.AutoPostBack = true;

            Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDowntimeExempt");
            switch (lbl.Text)
            {
                case "True":
                    ddl.SelectedValue = "1";
                    break;
                case "False":
                    ddl.SelectedValue = "0";
                    break;
                default:
                    ddl.SelectedValue = "-1";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void gridDowntime_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // User selected a shutdown, show its details
        bindDowntimeDetail();
        showDowntimeDetail(true);
    }

    protected void ddlDowntimeExempt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Applies the values selected in the exempt DDL to the database value
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;// <--Breakpoint
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

        int exempt_id = int.Parse(gridDowntime.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        bool? value = new bool?();
        if (ddl.SelectedValue.ToString() == "1")
        {
            value = true;
            LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, set to Exempt.", exempt_id));
        }
        else if (ddl.SelectedValue.ToString() == "0")
        {
            value = false;
            LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, set to Non-Exempt.", exempt_id));
        }
        else
        {
            value = null;
            LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, set to Unverified.", exempt_id));
        }

        RsDc.UPDATEISEXEMPT(exempt_id, value);


        // Update the gv
        BindDowntime();
    }

    protected void chkDowntimeExclude_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the Exclude checkbox is changed, update the Db
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender; // <--Breakpoint
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;

        int exempt_id = int.Parse(gridDowntime.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        RsDc.updateIsExcluded(exempt_id, chk.Checked);
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, has been Excluded.", exempt_id));
        }
        else
        {
            LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, has been Included.", exempt_id));
        }

        BindDowntime();
        bindDowntimeSummary();
    }

    protected void showDowntimeDetail(bool show)
    {
        // Shows or Hides a specific shutdowns detail
        downtimeDiv.Visible = !show;
        DowntimeSummaryDiv.Visible = !show;

        detailDiv.Visible = show;
        notesDiv.Visible = show;
        downtimeValueDiv.Visible = show;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Details

    protected void bindDowntimeDetail()
    {
        // Bind the detail for the selected shutdown
        // Get the values from the gv's datakeys
        int id_location = int.Parse(gridDowntime.SelectedDataKey[1].ToString());
        DateTime dtdown = DateTime.Parse(gridDowntime.SelectedDataKey[4].ToString());
        DateTime dtup = DateTime.Parse(gridDowntime.SelectedDataKey[5].ToString());
        int exempt_id = int.Parse(gridDowntime.SelectedDataKey[0].ToString());
        int adjust = int.Parse(ddlAdjust.SelectedValue);

        // Get the detail & apply
        DB db = new DB();

        gridDowntimeDetail.DataSource = db.getAllReasonForDownTimeAppend(id_location, dtdown, dtup, adjust, exempt_id);
        gridDowntimeDetail.DataBind();

        //CSS Header Sytle

        gridDowntimeDetail.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        gridDowntimeDetail.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        //Notes
        bindDowntimeNotes(exempt_id);
        bindDowntimeDetailsSummary(exempt_id);

    }

    protected void bindDowntimeDetailsSummary(int id)
    {
        gridDowntimeRecalc.DataSource = (from s in RsDc.Exempts where s.ID == id select s).ToList();
        gridDowntimeRecalc.DataBind();

        //CSS Header Sytle
        gridDowntimeRecalc.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        gridDowntimeRecalc.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }

    protected void bindDowntimeNotes(int id)
    {
        var query = (from s in RsDc.Exempts where s.ID == id select s.Details).Single();
        if (query != null)
        {
            tbNotes.Text = query.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void gridDowntimeDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // Highlights the GCB Open & GCB Closed Events
        // Also enables the mouse over highlight & click functionality
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "GCB opened")
            {
                e.Row.CssClass = "danger";
            }
            else if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "GCB closed")
            {
                e.Row.CssClass = "info";
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.CssClass = "";
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.backgroundColor='orange';");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#c8e4b6'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // Trigger an event when a row is clicked
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gridDowntimeDetail.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                // Set the last parameter to True 
                // to register for event validation. 
                row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gridDowntimeDetail, "Up$" + row.RowIndex, true);
            }
        }
        base.Render(writer);
    }

    protected void gridDowntimeDetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handles what will happen when a selected row is clicked
        // But first - is this a request to go back?

        if (e.CommandName == "Back")
        {
            // Return to the Downtime View
            // Hide the details
            showDowntimeDetail(false);

            //CSS Header Sytle
            gridDowntime.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            gridDowntime.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
        else if(e.CommandName == "Up")
        {
            // Get the selected row index
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

            // Get the user selected new details
            int exempt_id = Convert.ToInt32(gridDowntimeDetail.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);
            DateTime newUp = DateTime.ParseExact(gridDowntimeDetail.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string reason = gridDowntimeDetail.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].Text;

            // Get the original details from db.
            var orig = (from t in RsDc.getExemptsUpDown(exempt_id)
                        select new { DtDown = t.DTDOWN, DtUp = t.DTUP }).SingleOrDefault();

            DateTime Down = Convert.ToDateTime(orig.DtDown);
            //DateTime Up = Convert.ToDateTime(orig.DtUp);

            if (newUp >= Down)
            {
                int totalmins = Convert.ToInt32((newUp - Down).TotalMinutes);
                // Update the DB
                RsDc.updateExempt(exempt_id, newUp, totalmins, reason, false);
                LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, Uptime has been updated. Reason:{1}, Uptime:{2}.", exempt_id, reason, newUp.ToString()));
                // Highlight & Refresh times
                gridDowntimeDetail.Rows[rowIndex].CssClass = "info";
                bindDowntimeDetailsSummary(exempt_id);
                bindDowntimeDetail();
                showDowntimeDetail(true);
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "bootstrap_alert.warning('success', 'Success!', 'The record has been updated!');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                // User Feedback Error
            }
        }
    }

    protected void lnkReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reset the shutdown values back to there defaults
        int ExemptId = Convert.ToInt32(gridDowntimeDetail.DataKeys[0].Value);

        RsDc.resetExempt(ExemptId);
        LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, has been Reset.", ExemptId));
        bindDowntimeDetailsSummary(ExemptId);
        bindDowntimeDetail();
        showDowntimeDetail(true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "bootstrap_alert.warning('success', 'Success!', 'The record has been reset!');", true);
    }

    protected void lnkBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Return to the Downtime View
        // Hide the details
        showDowntimeDetail(false);

        //CSS Header Sytle
        gridDowntime.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        gridDowntime.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }

    protected void ddlAdjust_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Adjust the viewing window (minutes)
        bindDowntimeDetail();
        showDowntimeDetail(true);
    }

    protected void lnkSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the Note to the Db
        int ExemptId = int.Parse(gridDowntime.SelectedDataKey[0].ToString());

        RsDc.setExemptDetails(ExemptId, tbNotes.Text);
        LogMe.LogUserMessage(string.Format("Exempt ID:{0}, Notes have been updated '{1}'.", ExemptId, tbNotes.Text));
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "bootstrap_alert.warning('success', 'Success!', 'The record has been saved!');", true);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you add your code behind here..

Comment: Where in the code behinds do you put your breakpoints where the program do not go to?

Comment: I have marked breakepoints with "// <--Breakpoint" in the ddlDowntimeExempt_SelectedIndexChanged and chkDowntimeExclude functions.

Comment: Do you have a scriptmanager somewhere on the page (with EnablePartialRendering enabled)? <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" />

Comment: I have a <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="DefaultScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnablePageMethods="true"/> in my masterpage

Comment: Hi, I have added the LoadScriptsBeforeUI=true property to my ScriptManager however this has no effect on the ddlDowntimeExempt_SelectedIndexChanged and chkDowntimeExclude functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found this answer to this one myself, after further debugging I found that my `Control` for changing the date range for the `GridView` was being fired when changing the `CheckBox` value or the `DropDownList` value. Therefore the `CheckBox_CheckChanged` and `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged` events where not being fired.

I found that because I had multiple 'UpdatePanels' on the page all of them where being fired simultaneously.  Therefore by adding:

```
if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == UpdatePanelDateChanged.ClientID)
{
    // Fire date changed event here..
}
```

I was able to prevent my 'dateChanged' function from firing except when a specific `PostBack` call was being made to the `UpdatePanel` in my date selection `Control`.

See my question here: [C# ASP.NET CheckBox_OnCheckedChanged not firing as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490982/c-sharp-asp-net-checkbox-oncheckedchanged-not-firing-as-expected) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use something like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelDowntime" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAdjust" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
 <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlAdjust" /> 
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`UpdatePanel` stop postback .You have to  manually specify Async and Full Postback triggers. See these link [Control event not firing from within updatepanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540058/control-event-not-firing-from-within-updatepanel) and [Button click not working inside update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075538/button-click-not-working-inside-update-panel)