# C# ASP.NET CheckBox_OnCheckedChanged not firing as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, oncheckedchanged

I have an issue with both `Checkbox_OnCheckedChanged` and `Dropdownlist_OnSelectedIndexChanged` events not triggering the relevant functions in my code behind.

Both Controls are bound to values in a `GridView`. On the first `OnCheckedChanged` or `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event raised from the UI the functions in the code behind fire without error, however if I refresh my `UpdatePanel`, for example by changing the date range of the data inside the `GridView` and therefore loading more or less records, the `OnCheckedChanged` and `OnSelectedIndexChanged` functions are no longer called, however a `PostBack` occurs.

I believe that the functions are not being called as the function that rebinds the `GridView` is called instead:

```
 private void report_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        // Bind GridView here..
 }
```

however I cannot figure out why this happens.

I have a MasterPage:

```
namespace ReportingSystemV2.Reporting
{
public partial class Reporting : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Attach to DateChanged Event on DateChange UserControl to Function
        DateRangeSelect.dateChanged += new DateRangeSelect.dateChangedEventHandler(dtRgSel_dateChanged);
    }

    // Declare an event for the content pages
    public event EventHandler reportDateChanged;

    // Called on a date change event
    protected void dtRgSel_dateChanged(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise the event for content pages
        if (reportDateChanged != null)
            reportDateChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

This `MasterPage` has a `Control` for selecting my date range..

The main section of code for my control `ascx` code is:

```
<%--UpdatePanel to trigger datechange--%>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelDateChanged" OnLoad="UpdatePanelDateChanged_Load" >
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<%--When the date changes in javascript a postback is called in the updatepanel--%>
__doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanelDateChanged.ClientID %>', null);
```

And the the main section of code behind for this control is:

```
// Declare a delegate
public delegate void dateChangedEventHandler(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e);

// Declare an event for any pages that have the control
public event dateChangedEventHandler dateChanged;

protected virtual void OnDateChanged(DateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dateChangedEventHandler handler = dateChanged;

    // Raise the event
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}

protected void UpdatePanelDateChanged_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Trigger the controls public event
   OnDateChanged(new DateChangedEventArgs(DateTime.Parse(dates[0]), DateTime.Parse(dates[1])));

}
```

In my content page my `aspx` code is:

```
<%@ Page Title="Downtime" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Reporting/Reporting.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GensetDowntime.aspx.cs" Inherits="ReportingSystemV2.Reporting.GensetDowntime" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Reporting/Reporting.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ReportingSubContent" runat="server">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanelDowntime" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="downtimeDiv" runat="server">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gridDowntime" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-striped table-condensed"
                        OnRowDataBound="gridDowntime_RowDataBound"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridDowntime_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        DataKeyNames="ID,ID_Location,iddown,idup,dtdown,dtup,isexempt" EmptyDataText="No exempts in the selected period.">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exempt?">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDowntimeExempt" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
                                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDowntimeExempt_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Unverified</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDowntimeExempt" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"isexempt")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exclude?">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDowntimeExclude" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ISEXCLUDED")) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkDowntimeExclude_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Details" />
                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And finally my code behind for my content page is:

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Attach to UserControl Event on the MasterPage
        Master.reportDateChanged += new EventHandler(report_DateChanged);
    }

    // If the user changes the date lets update the table
    private void report_DateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Bind the gridview
    }

    // Function to be called when the ddl selectedindex is changed, only called on initial page load
    protected void ddlDowntimeExempt_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Applies the values selected in the exempt DDL to the database value
    }

    // function to be called when the checkbox checked state is change, again only called on the initial page loading - not after a postback
    protected void chkDowntimeExclude_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the Exclude checkbox is changed, update the Db
    }
```

The code above shows the `control` that uses javascript to `trigger` a `PostBack` on an `UpdatePanel`, which `triggers` a public event in the `Control`. The `MasterPage` has a function which is attached to the `Control` Event, this `MasterPage` functions updates a few values and triggers a new Event which is accessable to my `ContentPage`. The `ContentPage` attaches a function to this `MasterPage` Event and when the `DateRange` is changed it will load the data for the `GridView` and bind it.

Comment: We would like to appreciate your efforts, but not a lot of people have time to read entire question. Please post small program or code *(as small as possible)* so that we can replicate the issue. While making the small code, you might even find the solution by yourself.

Comment: I have updated my code and reduced it as much as possible, hopefully this is more acceptable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, by modifying the code in my `DateRangeControl` the `UpdatePanel` is no longer being triggered on all `PostBacks`, only those where it is called by `__doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanelDateChanged.ClientID %>', null);` in my `Javascript`.

```
protected void UpdatePanelDateChanged_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == UpdatePanelDateChanged.ClientID)
    {

        //Trigger Event
        OnDateChanged(new DateChangedEventArgs(DateTime.Parse(dates[0]), DateTime.Parse(dates[1])));

    }
}
```

Solution reference: `http://encosia.com/are-you-making-these-3-common-aspnet-ajax-mistakes/`

Answer (score 0):

Master pages append extra names at the beginning of controls in "child" pages. Most likely you are expecting the dropdown to have a name but it will have a different longer one like ctrl1$something$dropdown.

Check the ida using inspect in Chrome or dev tools to confirm that this is your problem first.

Comment: I have checked with dev tools and when the checkbox works correctly the name is: `ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ReportingSubContent$gridDowntime$ctl02$chkDowntimeExclude` and when it breaks it is `ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ReportingSubContent$gridDowntime$ctl14$chkDowntimeExclude` the only item changed here is ctl02 to ctl14 and this is because the CheckBox is further down the records in the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing async postback triggers. When an update panel partially posts back, it sends back the whole page, does the processing, and then returns only the portion that changed. Probably in that process, slight ID changes have taken place and then there are missed registrations. The `report_DateChanged` is fired most probably because it is the first control on the page that implements `IPostBackEventHandler` (because the postback on the checkbox and dropdown don't work any more)

To resolve that, explicitly add each control that should do an async postback to the update panel's triggers. like this:

```
protected void gridDowntime_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{  
    DropDownList ddl = e.Row.FindControl("ddlDowntimeExempt") as DropDownList;  
    CheckBox cb = e.Row.FindControl("chkDowntimeExclude") as CheckBox;  
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(ddl);  
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(cb);  
}
```

Comment: I have added the async postback registrations in as you have suggested, however this has had no effect. The behaviour is the same as previous?

Comment: How bizarre, and if you move the `DateRangeSelect.dateChanged` in your Master `Page_load` to `Page_PreInit`, does that change the behaviour?

Comment: By moving this the behaviour changes, in that the `dtRgSel_dateChanged` function in my Master no longer gets called when I change the date and the GridView data does not change.